# python pass method name to function

Tags: python, pandas

Im working with pandas dataframes and I would like to pass the aggregation method via a function parameter:

```
def aggregate(df, by, agg_method):
    return df.groupby(by).agg_method()
```

Obviously this doesnt work the same as passing a defined function since `agg_method` is being used as a method of `pd.DataFrame`. Ie. running

`aggregate(df, by, mean)`

raises an exception

`NameError: name 'mean' is not defined`

I assume because its not a defined function, rather Im trying to call a method of pandas (`pandas.DataFrame.mean()`)

Ideally I would avoid passing a string (or similar) to do something like

```
if agg_method == "mean":
    return df.groupby(by).mean()
```

It seems like there must be a better way. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can try lambda function here.

Comment: `getattr(df.grouby(by), agg_method)()`

Comment: Can't you just pass the panda method then?

Comment: If `agg_method` is a string, you can do `return getattr(df.groupby(by), agg_method)()`

Comment: You can just pass a string and use agg: `df.groupby(by).agg(agg_method)` where `agg_method` can be `'mean;`, `'var'`, `'std'`, `'nunique'`, `'size'`, etc... I think if it's available as a method on the groupby object, there is always a corresponding alias in agg.

Comment: Or if you want to pass it more general functions that act on your `Series` you can   `return df.groupby(by).agg(agg_method)` and call it like `aggregate(df, 'by_col', numpy.nanmean)`

Comment: I wasnt aware of the .agg() method! That appears to work and is super simple. Thanks!